# Differences in Powershell environments

Tags: powershell

Is there any difference between running a Powershell script:

- From the command line `powershell.exe -File my_scipt.ps1`
- From Powershell ISE (Open the script in the editor and press the green play button to run)
- From a Windows Powershell Host application?

And if there is a difference, is there a way in Powershell to check it?

The reason for asking this is that we are seeing one script have slightly different behaviour in these three environments, even though we had expected to see the same outcome. The behaviour is that a (3rd party non-public) .Net library we are using crashes in the second two environments, but works fine in the first one.

We have checked the obvious things, such as:

- directory of the powershell process set the same (which we set via `[System.IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory($my_path)` in the script)
- Powershell and .Net version (confirmed via identical `$PSVersionTable`)
- System path

My hope in asking this question is that there is some difference which we are unaware of, and that by identifying it we can resolve the crash we are seeing. I'd also be interested to hear of similar experiences from anyone here.

Comment: For example, does the console not exist in the second two environments?  I don't understand much about this though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072041/is-powershell-sta-apartment-state-preferred in v2 this is a notable difference.

Comment: Thanks. Just to summarise that link, one difference is the threading apartment type. Are there any others? And can you check the apartment type in the PS script?

Comment: There are a few known issues with Powershell ISE and the usage of Windows Forms in .NET code...

Comment: Thanks, can you post some links here for posterity?

Comment: *can you check the apartment type in the PS script* answer is in the link I provided. As for the known issues, see https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+forms+powershell+ise+issue and there is some good advice here https://blog.netnerds.net/2016/01/showdialog-sucks-use-applicationcontexts-instead/